# Kernel invocation produces error "error: a host function call cannot be configured". What is wrong with the invocation?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cuda

When compiling the following piece of code using nvcc -c mag_cuda.cu:

```
//Standard Libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

//Project Specific Header
#include "mag.hpp"

 __global__
  void indv_B_components(int *self_coords, int pole_coords[][3], double *indv_B[][3], int No_poles, int counter_1)
  {
    some code......
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------
  //------- Function to Calculate B Field at Each Pole -------
  //----------------------------------------------------------
  void calc_indv_B()
  {
    //declare namepspace for internal variables
    using namespace mag::internal;

    int *ppole_coords = &pole_coords[0][0];
    double *pindv_B;
    int self_coords[3];

    int num_threads_in_block = 256;
    int num_blocks = 32*2;

    cudaMallocManaged(&pindv_B, No_poles*3*sizeof(int));  


    //first loop to go over all poles
    for(int counter_1 = 0; counter_1 < No_poles; counter_1++)
      {
      //store coords of the current pole
      self_coords[0] = pole_coords[counter_1][0];
      self_coords[1] = pole_coords[counter_1][1];
      self_coords[2] = pole_coords[counter_1][2];


      indv_B_components<<<num_blocks, num_threads_in_block>>>(self_coords, ppole_coords,  pindv_B, No_poles, counter_1); 



      cudaDeviceSynchronize();
      }

    cudaFree(pindv_B);

    //return from function
    return;
  }
```

The following error is returned:

error: a host function call cannot be configured

Which refers to the line

```
indv_B_components<<<num_blocks, num_threads_in_block>>>(self_coords, ppole_coords,  pindv_B, No_poles, counter_1);
```

Since all the parameters are defined and the kernel the host device is calling a declared as `__global__` i don't know what could be causing this.

The header file mag.hpp is:

```
//make sure MAG_H_ module hasnt been defined multiple times
#ifndef MAG_H_
#define MAG_H_

//standard libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>


//Namespace for module
namespace mag
{


  //define functions
  ...


  void indv_B_components(int *self_coords, int *pole_coords, double *indv_B, int No_poles, int counter_1);

  void calc_indv_B();

  ...
}
#endif //MAG_H_
```

Any help?

Comment: It seems to me you are  only a few judicious edits away from an actual [MCVE]. The code you have posted does not fail to compile in the way you describe. Please fix the code to reproduce the problem and then you might get a useful asnwer

Comment: So you do, indeed have a forward declaration  `indv_B_components`  as a non `__global__` function despite all the protests that you don't

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One situation in which this error occurs is if you have just a "declaration" of your kernel function without a `__global__` specifier at the point where you call the kernel, for example:

```
void kernel();

void f()
{
    kernel<<<1, 1>>>();
}

__global__
void kernel()
{
}
```

[live demo here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:cuda,source:'%0A%0Avoid+kernel()%3B%0A%0Avoid+f()%0A%7B%0A%09kernel%3C%3C%3C1,+1%3E%3E%3E()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A__global__%0Avoid+kernel()%0A%7B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'CUDA+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:nvcc92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:cuda,libs:!(),options:'',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'NVCC+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+CUDA',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+NVCC+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

A declaration of a kernel function must include the `__global__` specifier:

```
__global__ void kernel();
```

Otherwise the declaration doesn't declare a kernel function but just a normal host function, which is why the compiler then complains as only a kernel function can be launched on the GPU…

Comment: I only have one declaration of "indv_B_components" with __global__ placed in front of it. I do not have the __global__ in the header file used with this file, however adding it produces other errors

Comment: @Aaron and at the point where you call the kernel, there *is* a declaration *with* `__global__` that appears *before* the kernel call?

Comment: @Aaron is this header file included in normal `.cpp` files as well? Because that'd explain why you get errors when you add `__global__`. There should be no need to have a declaration of a kernel function in a header that is used with normal `.cpp` files because there's no way you could call this kernel function from a normal `.cpp` file…

Comment: Yes there is a declaration with __global__ before the kernal call. The header file is used in other .cu files. Not .cpp files

Comment: @Aaron: Despite your protests, the scenario described in this answer is *exactly* what is happening in your code

Comment: @talonmies so is it the case that if i dont declare it as __global__ in the header file then it is classed as being declared as without the __global__ when compiling i.e. the kernal invocation takes the declaration in the  header file rather than the declaration in the .cu file? If that is that case, then what I have stated previously about the declaration in indeed wrong and this answer is correct

Comment: The source of the error is importing the namespace at the scope of the calling function. That overloads the function you previously defined as `__global__`  and breaks everything